# Need to start Oracle Coherence using Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat6, oracle-coherence

Can anyone tell me How to start Oracle Coherence using Tomcat?

Oracle coherence needs to be started as part of the tomcat startup script.
Below is our configuration we have 2 cluster, each cluster has 2 node.totally 4 nodes Each nodes on each physical server running jdk 1.6, spring framework. We are starting tomcat on the 4 physical servers The coherence needs to be started as part of the tomcat startup process on the 4 physical servers.

any ref link is appreciated?

Thanks in advance –

Comment: To get that straight: you want to use Java code running in Tomcat to start a service on a different machine?

Answer (score 0):

Each node has Oracle Coherence running?
You can write a bash script that starts Oracle Coherence before start Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to have Coherence running as part of the Tomcat processes themselves, if that is what you want to do. One way to do it is to load Coherence when the app loads, by including Coherence in the WAR (or on the CLASSPATH) and calling into CacheFactory when the application starts up.